# Не срабатывает onload

Tags: javascript

Где-то слышал, что onload вызывается после того, как страница целиком будет загружена. В связи с этим есть некоторый код:

```
<div onload="isSelected()"></div>
```

И есть некоторая функция:

```
function isSelected()
{
    alert('test');
}
```

И тем не менее функция не вызывается после загрузки всего документа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onload сработает только для body

Comment: Не только.

Comment: При загрузке страницы у body.

Comment: Да, про загрузку как-то проглядел.